# Proof of a Well-Known Fibonacci Identity Involving Cubes of Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

The following is due to Lucas in 1876:

$$F_{n + 1}^3 + F_n^3 - F_{n - 1}^3 = F_{3n}$$

I am unable to locate an elementary proof of this identity, and am unable to reproduce it myself. Would anyone mind sharing a proof or a source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice strategy is to use the elementary identity
$$ F_{n+m} = F_n F_{m-1} + F_{n+1}F_m. \tag1 $$
Use it to show that $\, a_n := F_{3n}\,$ satisfies the recursion
$$ a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1} + a_n. \tag2 $$
Now use it to express $\, F_{n-1} = F_{n+1} - F_n\,$ and hence express
$$ b_n := F_{n + 1}^3 + F_n^3 - F_{n - 1}^3 \tag3 $$
in terms of $\, F_n\,$ and $\, F_{n+1}.\,$ Verify that $\,a_n\,$ and $\,b_n\,$ satisfy the same recursion **and** initial values.
The idea is to express all of $\,b_n, b_{n+1}, b_{n+2}\,$ in terms of
$\,F_n, F_{n+1}\,$ using simple algebra.
$$ b_n = F_n(2F_n^2 -3F_nF_{n+1} +3F_{n+1}^2), \tag4 $$
$$ b_{n+1} = F_{n+1}(3F_n^2 +3F_nF_{n+1} +2F_{n+1}^2), \tag5 $$
$$ b_{n+2} = (F_n+F_{n+1})(2F_n^2 +7F_nF_{n+1} +8F_{n+1}^2). \tag6 $$

The [OEIS sequence A014445](https://oeis.org/A014445) is defined as $a_n$ and its recursion as well as its equivalence to $b_n$ is given in the entry.

Comment: Ok, the first relationship (2) can be shown with some playing around. Showing $b_n$ satisfies the same recursion seems to me to be roughly as difficult as the original problem, however.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most elegant way, but you can use the explicit formula for the Fibonacci numbers.
$$
F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \tau^n + \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\tau}\right)^n
$$
Here $\tau = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}, -1/\tau = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  This formula for $F_n$ can now be plugged into the left-hand side of the desired identity.
$$
\begin{align*} F_{n+1}^3 + F_n^3 - F_{n-1}^3 
= & \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \tau^{n+1} + \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\tau}\right)^{n+1}\right)^3\\
& + \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \tau^n + \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\tau}\right)^n\right)^3\\
& - \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \tau^{n-1} + \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\tau}\right)^{n-1}\right)^3
\end{align*}$$

Expanding out the terms takes a little work but will eventually lead to the desired expression 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \tau^{3n} + \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\tau}\right)^{3n}$ for $F_{3n}$.

As an example, considering the leading terms of the three cubes yields
$$
\frac{1}{5\sqrt{5}}\tau^{3n+3}+\frac{1}{5\sqrt{5}}\tau^{3n} - \frac{1}{5\sqrt{5}}\tau^{3n-3}
= \frac{1}{5\sqrt{5}}\left(\tau^3 + 1 - \frac{1}{\tau^3}\right)\tau^{3n}
$$
Since $\tau^3 = 2+ \sqrt{5}$ and $-1/\tau^3 = 2-\sqrt{5}$, we see that this simplifies to $(1/\sqrt{5})\tau^{3n}$, which is the first term of the expression for $F_{3n}$.

I leave the consideration of the other terms to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Use Somos' first identity to expand $F_{2n+n}$ and then expand again to get a bunch of terms, each the product of three Fibonacci numbers.
Take out the common factor $F_n$, and find the factor $F_n$ in your left-hand side.
The rest should be fairly easy.